# Scheme ignoring call to read-line

Tags: io, scheme, racket

When I run my scheme program it does not call the read-line procedure to wait for input from standard input. Rather it seems to be ignoring the call and returns an empty string. The piece of code where the error is coming from is

```
(define (turn probes)
  (let ((guess (get-guess probes)))
    (display guess)
    (let ((curr_scr (get-score)))
      (reduce-pool probes guess (score-to-str curr_scr)))))

(define (get-score)
  (newline)
  (display "> ")
  (regexp-split #px":" (read-line)))
```

So when I call get-score the return value is "" instead of going to standard input. The expected return after reading from standard in is something like (1 2) and the first element is eventually passed to make-string thus resulting in the following error:

```
make-string: expects type <non-negative exact integer> as 1st argument, given: ""; other arguments were: #\B
```

This is my first time programming in scheme so I'm very confused as to why this is happening. Im running this on Ubuntu 12.04 with mzscheme which I believe is just the old name for Racket. Any ideas for what is going on? Do you need more information?

Comment: Do you have the _whole_ program?

Comment: its over 100 lines.. should i post it all here? thanks

Comment: No, but try to make a small minimal program that can replicate the same problem you're seeing. See: http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve

Comment: I just tossed it on github https://github.com/MarkAWard/mastermind-solver

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It seems to be related to your previous uses of `(read)`. At the bottom of your code, replace both

`(define ... (read))`

with

`(define ... (string->number (read-line)))`.

Comment: these seems to be working. just running into more scheme issues. :-/ who knows I may be back..

Answer (score 1):

Are you running your program in the Racket REPL? If so, the first `(read-line)` call always returns an empty string on the first call. You can replicate this by running `(list (read-line) (read-line))` in the REPL.

Read this thread for more details: http://lists.racket-lang.org/users/archive/2011-January/043731.html.

Answer (score 0):

Following the thread https://lists.racket-lang.org/users/archive/2011-January/043736.html

I suggest, instead of

```
(list (read-line) (read-line))
```

to do

```
(begin (read-line) (read-line))
```

So you don't get a list of a single line, but a line.